# Permanent residency catch 22 : Can't get a job for PR, can't get PR without a job

Tags: visa, australia, residency, working, employment

I'm currently studying business (marketing) in Australia and I think I've hit a snag. I love it here and want to work here after graduation on a full time basis, but nobody wants to hire me because I do not have PR, yet I can't get PR without being sponsored by an employer.

I have invested a massive amount of time on job hunting, applying to graduate programs, going to career fairs and trying to network, going to events held by the university and trying to network...all of them have pretty much hit a dead end. Most employers immediately stop talking to me when they realise that I do not have permanent residency, even if they were previously very excited to hear more about my work experience just moments before. I cannot even obtain an internship for the same reason.

I can apply for a work visa after graduation, but it is temporary (for a few years) and employers are simply not interested when I mention it.

At the same time it, it doesn't look like I can apply for PR unless I am studying in certain fields, which would require me to do post graduate studies in another field (e.g. law), which would take a LOT of money...money that I simply do not have. I don't think I'm eligible for any kind of student loans here either.

Short of some sort of miracle happening (getting married, winning the lottery, try to become a high level executive elsewhere first before migrating, etc), my dream seems out of reach. My Australian friends are sympathetic, but none of them are business owners or high level executives who can help. The ones who are working full time say they could put in a good word for me, but they don't have the seniority to do anything about company hiring policies.

I seem to be stuck in a terrible catch 22 here. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could stay and work here after graduation? The only employers willing to hire me are the ones who have made it clear it would be a temporary basis only...places like Maccas or other retail establishments.

Answer (score 7):

The reason they are not willing to sponsor you for PR is that they can find employees who are as good (or better) for the job, but do not come with such requirement. Generally speaking for an employer to go the extra mile for a potential employee, there either must be a shortage or that candidate must be extraordinary.

I understand that this may not be something you want to hear, as you say you've put a lot of effort towards making yourself attractive. But that is the reality of job markets that if you can't find a job, then that means that there are more suitable candidates.

It seems like your route to staying in Australia is to work the temporary jobs and, on the side, make yourself a lot more attractive to potential employers.